# Windows forms coming back blank

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anyone see why my form boxes of latitude longtitude and elevation are coming back blank? I have been looking for hours and can't see why!

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataPoints mydataPoints = new dataPoints();
            dataPoint a = mydataPoints.getItem(0);
            latTextBox.Text = a.CurLatitude;
            longTextbox.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
            eleTextBox.Text = a.CurElevation;

        }
    }
}
```

Above is my form

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    public class dataPoints
    {
        List<dataPoint> Points;
        public void DataPoints()
        {
            Points = new List<dataPoint>();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:/users/tom/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/DistanceCalculator3/DistanceCalculator3/TextFile1.txt");
            string input;
            while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] bits = input.Split(',');
                dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[0],bits[1],bits[2]);              
                Points.Add(a);  


            }

            tr.Close();
        }

        internal dataPoint getItem(int p)
        {
            if (p < Points.Count)
            {
                return Points[p];
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my points class that draws the points from a text file seperated by a comma

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    class dataPoint
    {
        private string latitude;
        private string longtitude;
        private string elevation;

        public dataPoint(string Latitude, string Longtitude, string Elevation)
        {

            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.latitude = Latitude;
            this.longtitude = Longtitude;
            this.elevation = Elevation;

        }

        public string CurLongtitude { get { return this.longtitude; } }
        public string CurLatitude { get { return this.latitude; } }
        public string CurElevation { get { return this.elevation; } }

    }
}
```

Above is the class that holds individual points and sends them back

Comment: They are meant to show whatever is in the text file, in this case, 1.2,3.4 and 1.5

Comment: Learn to use the debugger and step through your code. This will prove invaluable here and in the future.

Comment: Explain _"coming back blank"_. Put a breakpoint in the `DataPoints()` constructor, see if the file gets read successfully. Do you actually type text in `textBox1`, does the `textBox1_TextChanged()` method get called?

Comment: Sorry, by coming back blank I mean the text file text is not being put into the textbox as i intend it to be, the text box once the program is run is blank. I can still write things in it but the data from the text file is not there

Comment: See my answer to the 'blank' issue.  @CodeCaster, I think its fairly obvious what OP meant by the question.

Comment: @RichardSchneider I was hinting that OP put a breakpoint somewhere to inspect his variables, to see which one is "blank", or `null` as we call it.

Comment: Why is everyone down voting.  Its a legitimate question, while naive, with a code example.  Don't be so righteous! I've just marked as a favourite to  counteract the down down votes.

Comment: @RichardSchneider probably because of the research effort that is required. This is just _"this doesn't work, debug it for me"_, which is not interesting nor will it help future visitors.

Comment: @CodeCaster you may be right, but my job is to help OPs.  Debugging is a skill you and I utilise every day, but for new comers its as hard as writing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textBox1_TextChanged` is only called when the end-user changes a text box.  Your code seems to indicate you want to initialise the text boxes.

I recommend overriding the OnLoad method, and then setting the text boxes.  Something like:

```
protected override OnLoad()
{
        dataPoints mydataPoints = new dataPoints();
        dataPoint a = mydataPoints.getItem(0);
        latTextBox.Text = a.CurLatitude;
        longTextbox.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
        eleTextBox.Text = a.CurElevation;
}
```

I have not checked out the rest of the code.  But this is first issue to address.

I'm assuming that new dataPoints() will read in whatever data you are interested in.  It is **NOT** a standard practice to have a constructor loading in data.  However, your code implies the intention.

Comment: Ok sorted it, I just needed to initialise it at the start like so..

Comment: `public Form1()
        {

            dataPoints mydataPoints = new dataPoints();
            InitializeComponent();
            dataPoint a = mydataPoints.getItem(0);
            latTextBox.Text = a.CurLatitude;
            longTextbox.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
            eleTextBox.Text = a.CurElevation;          
         
        }`

Comment: Glad its working.  But its better not to do i/o in a constructor. Add an OnLoad() method.  Its purpose is to populate the `Form` once the UI is ready.

Comment: Sorry to keep this going, please feel free to stop responding :P When I use the OnLoad it doesn't go green and keeps asking for a return value..

Answer (score 3):

At least one of your issues is:

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    public class dataPoints
    {
        List<dataPoint> Points;
        public void DataPoints()
        {
        ...
```

Your class is called `dataPoints` but you've attempted to create a constructor but called it `DataPoints` (notice the case). This code won't get run when you create a `dataPoints` object.

As Shadow Wizard wizard points out, you can't have a return type for your constructor. Your compiler would tell you that if you match the case.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but the code does run and the class and constructor are different through capitalisation. I have tried changing the public void Datapoints to a different name and it does not fix the blank textboxes.

Comment: As stated, this is just *one* of your issues. See Richard Schneider's answer for another issue.

Answer (score 2):

C# is case sensitive and has special syntax for constructors. As is stands, the method you have as "constructor" will never run.

Correct code would be:

```
public class dataPoints
{
    List<dataPoint> Points;
    public dataPoints()
    {
        //constructor code here...
    }
}
```

As you can see, constructor can't have return type as well.

Comment: Not yet, im trying to understand what protected overide is. On the below answer!

Comment: It just means that better practice is executing your code in the `OnLoad` event of the form instead of in the `OnChange` event of your text box.

Comment: I see, I found that executing the code under the form method works. It makes sense to input the data after the form has loaded.